# C++ fscanf comma text file info strings and numbers

Tags: c++, scanf

I'm trying to read from a .txt file that looks like this:

```
100054545
```

To do that, I am using this code:

```
int main() {
    int ra;

    FILE *archivo;

    fopen_s(&archivo,"people.txt", "r");

    if (NULL==archivo){ printf("Error"); }
    else {
        fscanf_s(archivo,"%i);
    }


    cout<<"Code1: " <<rb<<endl;



    fclose(archivo);
    system("pause");
    };
}
```

Comment: why not use C++ input methods?

Answer (score 1):

You use the wrong format for the string. String are scanned with `"%s"`. The `c` in `"%c"` stands for character (as in a *single* character), the `s` for string. You should probably learn to read the documentation better.